# Finding subimage/template/object from mainImage/scene using opencv android

Tags: android, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-comparison

I want to find that does smalller image or subimage is part of larger image or not? and if it is part of it then want to know its coordinates.

For doing that, i was using template matching method of opencv. It was working fine if the size of subimage is exactly same as size of part of Main Image(where it matches). But if i change the size/scale the sub image then template matching is not able to do what i what i want to perform. Can anyone know other methods of how to do that and please if possible give me the code to find it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/2545927

Comment: nice answer there, but one of the main problem is how to implement that in android. The SIFT and SURF are the 2 methods which i know about(both are part of opencv), but problem with both of them is that both are removed from nonfree package in opencv library from version 2.4.0 , so i m not able to use it

Comment: I got solution to my own question, check out the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898480/object-detection-with-opencv-feature-matching-with-a-threshold-similarity-score/20994113#20994113

Comment: @IDontKnowAnything, there are more algorithms similar to SURF and SIFT and are available on Android. I recommend that you start with ORB and read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14808429/1085483

Comment: I have seen ORB earlier but it is having very less accuracy, thats why that is not preferrable